# fixed bar width in spineplot

Tags: r, spine

I'm using spineplot to visualize conditional density. As a default, width of bars indicate relative density of data (like height of bar on a histogram). However, this is not OK for me now. How the "get rid" of this feature and gain constant bar width? Alternatively: how to make x axis proportional to x values, i.e. the breaks?

```
data("plasma",package="HSAUR2")
spineplot(ESR~fibrinogen,data=plasma)
```

[image]